# Docker, php and python

Tags: php, python, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem to getting php to call a python script. I don´t know how I should get php to have access to python via `exec`.

Her is my yml file:

```
nginx:
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
        - 80:80
    links:
        - php
    volumes_from:
        - app

php:
    build: ./php/
    expose:
        - 9000
    links:
        - mysql
    volumes_from:
        - app

app:
    image: php:7.0.11-fpm
    volumes:
        - ./src:/var/www/html
    command: "true"

mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes_from:
        - data
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
        MYSQL_DATABASE: project
        MYSQL_USER: project
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: project

data:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
        - /var/lib/mysql
    command: "true"

phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
        - 8888:80
    links:
        - mysql
    environment:
        PMA_HOST: mysql
```

Should I add a python container also? Or whats best here?

Comment: can you add some more details to your question please. How/where is that PHP supposed to interact with your Python script?

Comment: I have index.php on the nginx server. When I go to host/index.php I want to execute run_me.py, and the result should be displayd on the index.php page.

Comment: I'd start by adding a python container. Though this seems like a strange requirement. What does `run_me.py` do?

Comment: Yeah - like @JonStirling says, this seems strange. If you're calling a python script you can run PHP and Python in the same container and make the call but I'd bet the Python script could be replaced with PHP.

Comment: I want to run some webdriver tests via python.